# Need help understanding Dedekinds construction of the Reals (section from Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis

I got to the part where we want to show y (gamma) is a cut in **R**. The paragraph goes as follows:

*The ordered set **R** has The least upper bound property.
To prove this let A be a non-empty subset of **R** and assume that beta in **R** is an upper bound of A.
Define gamma to be the union of all alpha in A. In other words p is in gamma iff p is an alpha for some alpha in A. We shall prove that gamma is in **R** and that gamma equals the supremem of A.*

So up until this point, I understand where it’s going, here is where the trouble begins:

*Since A is not empty, there exists an alpha in A. This alpha is not empty.* **Why can we assume this alpha is not empty?**

Comment: Isn't that simply part of what it means to be an element of the $\mathbf R$ we're constructing?

Comment: Every Dedekind cut is by definition a non-empty subset of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oops you’re right. This is what happens when you don’t go back to read the original hypothesis. Thank you!

Comment: @Troposphere yes I forgot what we started with...thank you

Comment: @Ash: You’re welcome!